look up the value of a page based on the values on a page
I have a main table with one column listed as Wk 1, Wk 2 etc to Wk 53. I want columns B to H to show the dates in tabs Wk1 to Wk53 cells F3 to L3 respectively. so B3 is ='Wk 1'!F3 etc.
but I dont want to spend hours type ='Wk 2'!F3, ='Wk 2'!G3 etc in every cell.
As the week/tab name is already in column A, Is there a way to reference this field and add it in the look up code?



Use the INDIRECT and ADDRESS functions.

I don't know if I understood this description correctly due to the lack of illustrations.
If it is something similar to the image below, then in cell B3, you can put the formula:
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN()+4,,,$A3))

And copy right and down to the corresponding cells.


Not quite what I was looking for but pointed me the right way. Thanks

Used =HYPERLINK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN()+4,,,$A2)),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN()+4,,,$A2)))
but the format is all wrong for a hyperlink

What is the target of this hyperlink?

Maybe try this way: =HYPERLINK("#"&ADDRESS(3,COLUMN()+4,,,$A2),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN()+4,,,$A2))).Cell must be properly formatted as date according to local settings.

tried
=HYPERLINK(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN()+4,,,$A2),TEXT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN()+4,,,$A2)),"DD/MM/YYYY"))
Although this displays the correct format, it doesn't open the cell in the current workbook

=HYPERLINK("#"&ADDRESS(3,COLUMN()+4,,,$A2),TEXT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN()+4,,,$A2)),"DD/MM/YYYY"))
Works beautifully thanks!

You could use
Create a 3-D reference to the same cell range on multiple worksheets - Microsoft Support
so enter in B3:
=VSTACK('Wk 1:Wk 53'!F3:L3)



Is VSTACK available to 2003 and 2021?

For sure not in 2003. I don't have access to Excel 2021 now to verify it. Are you getting an error in your version? Also, what is the exact version you're using?
